# Tag based policy for s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am looking to create a tag based policy for a user(david) to access only those s3 buckets where costCenter tag has a value of 12345 . I have created a bucket and tagged it with costCenter 12345 but i am still not able to perform a list on it . Here is my policy .

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:ResourceTag/costCenter": "12345"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried with following condition .

```
"Condition": {"StringLike": {"aws:ResourceTag/costCenter": "12345"
```

But in both the situations when i do .

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket-with-tag --profile david
```

I get

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Tab-based [authorization in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) is **only for objects**, not for buckets:

> Amazon S3 supports tag-based authorization for **only** object resources.

However, `ListObjectsV2` is bucket-level action, not object-level. So your policy will not work. Also for object-level tags, S3 has [additional](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tagging-and-policies.html) condition keys.